# Salesforce: Queries yield different record counts in despite of same condition on the same object

Tags: salesforce, soql

first query, record count = 10k:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >=2020-04-18T01:03:21Z AND LastModifiedDate < 2020-04-19T01:03:21Z
```

second query, record count > 10k:

```
SELECT Id "and several other fields" FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2020-04-18T01:03:21Z AND LastModifiedDate <2020-04-19T01:03:21Z
```

Question:
Why do the record counts differ? In both cases only the rows that have been modified in the given time period should be retrieved, imho.
What do I miss?

Comment: Are you running both queries in developer console query editor?

Comment: I am running the queries via Pentaho / Kettle. Done that for weeks, never had that issue yet until yesterday.
Will have full access tomorrow, i.e. will try out SystemModStamp instead of LastModifiedDate. Will filter the additional IDs via Excel / vlookup on top of that. As of now, I got only the error log.